# How to accept space separated inputs as separate inputs in JAVA using BufferReader

Tags: java, input

I tried reading the space-separated inputs `5 3` for my code using `Scanner` class which works fine using `nextInt()` method. When I switched to `BufferReader` class for faster I/O, using `readLine()` does not accept the space-separated inputs as separate integers.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    
    try{
        InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);    
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r); 
    int t= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
    
    while(t-->0){
        
    int mel=Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
    
    int ban=Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
    
    System.out.println(cho(mel,ban));
    
        
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        return;
    }
    
    }
    
    public static int cho(int m,int b)
    
    {
        if(m==0 || b==0 || (m==b))
        {
            return (m+b);
        }
        else
        {
           return m>b? cho((m-=b),b): cho(m,(b-=m));
            
           
            
        }
    }
}
```

`**Inputs**  2 5 3 10 10` 
`**Expected Outputs**  2 20`

`**My Outputs**
2
5 3

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());` reads the whole line and parses it to integer value so it expects only single integer value in the string. If you want to parse multiple integers from a line separated by space you first need to split it (or use do a regex search). For example `br.readLine().split(" ");` and then iterate over the array of strings and parse them as integers